# amid a violent turf war on the most active route into the bloc

Tags: grammar

> A lone gunman is spotted in the no-man’s land between Serbia and Hungary, near the European Union nation’s heavily guarded eastern frontier.
> Hooded and masked, he aims an assault rifle at the CCTV cameras that have monitored his breach of the metres high, razor-wire topped border fence separating the two countries.
> Behind him, dozens of undocumented, illegal migrants prepare to follow, their sights set on breaking into the bloc beyond.
> In their way stand Hungarian border guards, determined to prevent yet another breach at what has become a weak link in the EU’s external frontiers.
> The gunman, Hungarian authorities say, **is** part of a Taliban takeover of people smuggling operations **led** by the Haqqani terror network **amid a violent turf war on the most active route into the bloc**.
> György Bakondi, Hungary’s national security adviser, said he had shared intelligence reports with Nato that prove the Afghan secret service was attempting to exploit Europe’s mounting migration crisis.

Source: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2023/11/17/eu-immigration-slingshot-wielding-migrants-storm-borders/?WT.mc_id=tmgoff_youtube_youtube-community

---

Where is the bold part attached? "**is**" or "**led**"?
What does the bold part modify?

Comment: The "takeover" is occuring "amid a violent turf war". The takeover is led by the Haqqani terror network. What is being taken over are "people-smuggling operations"

Comment: **amid a violent turf war** is a supplemental prepositional phrase that gives the "backdrop" or the conditions in which the takeover is happening.

Comment: @TimR is "**amid a violent turf war on the most active route into the bloc**" a part of the reduced relative clause with "**led** by the Haqqani terror network"?